# Xcode: Linking external framework in a framework project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I am creating a framework (say My.framework) which will make use of an external framework (say External.framework).
I don't want to include External.framework in My.framework, since it increases my framework's binary size.
How do i build My.framework, so that the host project works only if the External.framework is present?

Answer (score 0):

You can create workspace, with your App, your framework and external framework.

In your framework in target general tab add external framework to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

In project two if you include your framework but without external framework, compiler will signal error.

Comment: I tried it, but i am still able to run it in another project, even if i don't include the external.framework. I am guessing the symbols are being copied to My.framework.